# To Read XML file in Android

Tags: android

I was tried to read XML file using SAXParser class, But it is displaying some special character such as [],<<..>>` etc. Can you help me to read XML with excluding special chars.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Normalization for the Node Content. `normalize` method helps for that. check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#normalize())